# Identifying bug in Django code that's causing my app to redirect infinitely in the browser

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

I have a Django template that lists all chat groups a user is a part of. Clicking the name of the displayed groups takes the user inside the said group. It's a simple HTML GET request: `<a href="{% url 'private_group' unique %}">Group name</a>`, where `unique` is the uuid related to the group.

Currently, clicking the group name is sending me to infinite redirects (output given all the way at the end). What is going on? Please help me troubleshoot it, details are as follows:

Relevant parts of **urls.py** are:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
url(r'^group/(?P<slug>[\w.@+-]+)/$', auth(private_group), name='private_group'),
url(r'^group/private/$', auth(PrivateGroupView.as_view()), name='private_group_reply'),
)
```

`private_group` is a simple view method like so:

```
def private_group(request, slug=None, *args, **kwargs):
    request.session['unique_id'] = slug #setting session variable
    return redirect("private_group_reply")
```

On the other hand, `private_group_reply` is a class based view. Some of the view code is as follows (cut out a significant number of lines since I'm assuming they're unrelated):

```
class PrivateGroupView(CreateView):
    model = Reply
    form_class = PrivateGroupReplyForm      
    template_name = "private_group_reply.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(PrivateGroupView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if self.request.user.is_authenticated():
            unique = self.request.session['unique_id'] #reading session variable
            context["unique"] = unique
            return context
```

Ask me for more information if this doesn't suffice.

---

Infinite redirects:

```
[29/Mar/2016 19:37:56] "GET /groups/ HTTP/1.1" 200 10077
[29/Mar/2016 19:37:58] "GET /group/12bcd803-2e1a-47b4-9b91-dff279a82a73/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[29/Mar/2016 19:37:58] "GET /group/private/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[29/Mar/2016 19:37:58] "GET /group/private/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[29/Mar/2016 19:37:58] "GET /group/private/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[29/Mar/2016 19:37:58] "GET /group/private/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[29/Mar/2016 19:37:58] "GET /group/private/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[29/Mar/2016 19:37:58] "GET /group/private/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
```

Comment: The problem could be the `auth` decorator, which you haven't shown.

Comment: Please show your full urls.py.

Comment: @Alasdair `auth` is simply `from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required as auth` in urls.py

Comment: What happens if you swap `private_group` and `private_group_reply` lines in the urls?

Comment: @DanielRoseman: I edited the question to show a urls.py snippet. Do you want more detail?

Comment: `\w+` will match `private` so it is just using the same url every time, Note: you might want to escape the `.` as well (`\.`)

Comment: Whatever will I do without you guys. Great catch.

Comment: @Sayse: so that will be (?P<slug>[\w\.@+-]+)?

Comment: @HassanBaig - Yes, `[\w.@-]+` would have been the same as `\.+` since `.` is any character in regex where I assume you wanted to match the character `.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`(?P<slug>[\w.@+-]+)` matches the string "private". That means your redirection to /group/private is always being caught by the private_group view, which redirects back to itself.

Swap the order of those URLs so that the private one comes first.